# Flow of submanifolds and normal components

Tags: differential-geometry

Informally stated: If two vector fields have equal normal component to a submanifold (for all time), do the flows of this submanifold along the vector fields have equal image?

More rigorously, my question is as follows:

Set-up: Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $X_t$ a (possibly time-dependent) vector field. We also fix a submanifold $L \subset M$ and a Riemannian metric on $M$. We suppose $M$ is complete.

Then we know that for every time $t$, there is some submanifold
$$
L_t \subset M
$$ 
given by the flow of $L$ along $X_t$.

Suppose we have another time-dependent vector field $Y_t$ satisfying the following:

For every time $t$, and for every point $x \in L_t$, the vector fields $X_t$ and $Y_t$ have equal normal component to $L_t$. That is, $X_t - Y_t$ is contained in the tangent space $T_x L_t$.

Question: If $L_t'$ denotes the time $t$ flow of $L$ along $Y_t$, does it follow that $L_t' = L_t$ as subsets of $M$?